# Show/Hide entire box content with RadioButton Shiny

Tags: r, shinyjs

I have 3 boxes in the dashboard body. When `radioButton` in selected to "P3G", box1 and box3 should appear i.e hide box2. When `radiobutton` is selected to "Chose File", box2 and box3 should appear. I have the below code using shinyjs but it is not working as required i.e. not hiding complete box contents as coded in `observeEvent`. Any help?

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(width=200,
                        sidebarMenu(id="tabs",
                                    menuItem("Input File", tabName = 
"tab1",icon = icon("fas fa-file"))))

body <- tabItem(tabName = "tab1",value="file_nput",h2("Select file"),
            fluidRow(useShinyjs(),
                     radioButtons("file_rd",label= "Chose Dataset:",
                                  choices = list("P3G","Chose File"),selected = "P3G"),
                     box( id ="box1",title = "Default Sample", width = 7, status = "info",
                          tabPanel("Sample Info",value="p3_samples",
                                   DT::dataTableOutput("p3_table"))),

                     box(id= "box2", title = "Uploaded Sample", width = 7, status = "info", 
                         tabsetPanel(id = "sam_tab",
                                     tabPanel("Upload", value="upload_file",
                                              fileInput(inputId ="FILE",label = "Upload file",multiple=FALSE,
                                                        accept = c(".txt")),
                                              checkboxInput('header', label = 'Header', TRUE),
                                              actionButton("createdb","Create DB")),

                                     tabPanel("File Info",value="samples",tableOutput("summary"),icon = icon("info"),
                                              DT::dataTableOutput("full_table"),actionButton("upload","Proceed")))),
                     box(id = "box3" ,status = "info", width = 5,
                         tabBox(id = "infobox", height = "100%", width = "100%",
                                tabPanel("Instructions",h4("Instructions for uploading valid input file"))))))

ui<- shinyUI(dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "TestApp", titleWidth = 150),sidebar,dashboardBody(tabItems(body))))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
     observeEvent(input$file_rd, {
       if (input$file_rd == "P3G") {
         shinyjs::hide(id = "box2", anim=TRUE)
         }else {
           shinyjs::hide(id = "box1",anim=TRUE)
           }
     })
     } 

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use

> [conditionalPanel()](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/conditionalPanel.html)

so conditionalPanel for box1 will be like this:

```
conditionalPanel('input.file_rd === "P3G"', box(id = 'box1', ...)
```

and for box2 and box3:

```
conditionalPanel('input.file_rd != "P3G"', box(id = 'box2', ...), box(id = 'box3', ...)
```

Comment: Thanks. `conditionalPanel` does the trick. But since i need box3 in both conditions, the box3 code or content has to be written within both conditional panels. This is not very bad but when the box content is too big then the code looks repetitive. Therefore, i was trying to use `shinyjs` it see if it may work.

Comment: If you don't need to hide box3, you can remove that box code from conditionalPanel and place it after. Hope i understand you right.